# How to call a method of a specific class from another class (created in this specific class)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

I created a TTModelViewController. in the createModel Method i created a TTURLRequestModel. after Loading content in the TTURLRequestModel i want to call a method in my TTModelViewController.

TTModelViewController

```
- (void) createModel {
     requestModel = [[singlePostModel alloc] initWithId:@"54"];
}

- (void)didLoadModel:(BOOL)firstTime {
      NSLog(@"loaded");
}
```

TTURLRequestModel (singlePostModel)

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
      //doing something
     [super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
}
```

first i thought "didLoadModel" gets called after requestDidFinishLoad was called, but its before.

So, how can i call a method in my TTModelViewController after request is finished loading?
is there a method that already does that and i only have to overwrite this? or something else?

thanks

// if knowbody knows how to do this with three20, anybody can tell me how to do this in general?

### edit

---

the solution of the first post works fine now, but i still got a warning that the function i call to my object doesnt exist:

```
@interface TTModelViewController {
}

- (void)modelFinishedLoading;

@end
```

and now i call that method in my models class

```
[controller modelFinishedLoading];
```

at this point xcode throws a warning "no -modelFinishedLoading method found".

why? i implemented it in the interface and also in the implementation part of TTModelViewController.

does that have to do with this @class at my singlePostModel?

```
@class singlePostViewController;
@interface singlePostModel : TTURLRequestModel
```

Comment: Why not just call it in requestDidFinishLoad?

Comment: thats a method in my "requestModel". but i want to call a function of my TTModelViewController (where "requestModel" is initialised)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to subclass `TTURLRequestModel`, which I suspect you've already done based on the name of your class (`singlePostModel`).  In that subclass, add a member variable that you can use to point back to your `TTModelViewController`.  Something like:

Class Definition:

```
class TTModelViewController;
@interface singlePostModel : TTURLRequestModel {
    TTModelViewController *controller;
} 

- (id) initWithId:(String *)id forController:(TTModelViewController *)controller;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation singlePostModel {
- (id) initWithId:(String *)id forController:(TTModelViewController *)mvc {
  if (self = [super initWithId:id]) {
    controller = mvc;
  }
}

- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
  [controller callMyMethodHere];
  [super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
}

@end
```

When you initialize it then, you would use:

```
- (void) createModel {
  requestModel = [[singlePostModel alloc] initWithId:@"54" forController:self];
}
```

Unless you have another way to get to your `TTModelViewController`, like through the app delegate singleton, in which case, that could work just as well, as long as you don't mind the coupling.

For example, your app delegate has a reference to the main View Controller for the application because it is set up from the main NIB.  That is easily accessible using

```
((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).myMainViewController
```

Comment: i'll give it a try this afternoon. can you please explain your last sentence? i dont understand it :(

Comment: Expanded the answer to explain my last sentence.

Comment: ill accept your answer, but one last thing. check my edit above.

Comment: You need to include the header file of the class you are calling the method on in your .m file for the warning to go away